# Prayer in the Ran at the end of Neddarim

Tags: tefilla, talmud-gemara, commentaries, rishonim, tractate-nedarim

Printed at the end of Ran's pirush on maseches Neddarim, before the hadran, is a prayer for Torah and the Beis HaMikdosh. It reads:

א-לקים משמים יאיר עינינו בתורתו כאור החמה שבעתים. 
ויזכנו לראות בבנין ירושלים אמן.

I'll assume this is actually from the Ran unless proven otherwise. But why this particular prayer at the end of this masechta, and why any prayer at all? He doesn't seem to have put any type of prayers at the end of the other masechtos we have his pirush on.